# beamer section page: \insertsection color

Tags: beamer, luatex

I am trying to set a different section page template:

```
\setbeamercolor{section title}{fg=blue}

\setbeamertemplate{section page}
{
    \begin{minipage}[b][\paperheight]{\textwidth}
        \vfill
        \vspace{3cm}
        \qag
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{section title}\huge\textbf{\insertsection} % works with \inserttitle
        \vfill
        \vspace{1mm}
    \end{minipage}
}
```

With `\inserttitle`, color is as expected, but with `\insertsection`, the text is always red. What am I doing wrong?

It's driving me crazy.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

After hitting the submit button, I found the reason: The color is overwritten by the hyperlink setup, as the section is a link.

```
% hyperref
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks} % this overwrote the color in the template
```